# WP Query between posts custom fields

Tags: posts, wp-query, custom-field

I've tried doing a WP_Query based on a custom field, which name is 'date' and value is something like '14/01/2015'. I want the query to give results when 'date' is between today and tomorrow.

All I've tried so far is this:

```
$y=date('d/m/Y',strtotime('yesterday'));
$t=date('d/m/Y',strtotime('tomorrow'));
$o=date('d/m/Y',strtotime('today'));

echo "yesterday: ".$y;
echo "today: ".$o;
echo "tomorrow: ".$t;
$d=new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category__in' => array(4),
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'data',
            'value'     => array($y,$t),
            'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'      => 'DATE',
        )
    )
);
```

But is giving me posts which 'date' is also 25/01/2015. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advice

Comment: Your date format is backwards, though it may sometimes appear to work, you will get incorrect results in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,
I've used this:

```
$d=new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category__in' => array(4),
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'data',
                'value' => $t,
                'compare' => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'data',
                'value' => $o,
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

Instead of the other one before, and everything is working fine.

Comment: I'll try to remember :)